# Suggested way to load arbitrary data

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to load config-like values from my database so I can use them in screens. They're regular resources, except that I don't always want them in the menu (user-role based).

Right now I'm pre-loading the data using a custom saga like so:

```
export function* dataSaga() {
  yield put(crudGetList('locales', { page: 1 , perPage: 9999999 }, {}, {}));
  yield put(crudGetList('config', { page: 1 , perPage: 9999999 }, {}, {}));
}
```

Which works fine and also allows me to access the data in my resources by connecting them.  The problem is that when I start hiding items from the menu by removing `list` from the `Resource`, this no longer works and the data is fetched but not persisted to the store.

Is there another way I can do this (besides using my own keys in the store)? I prefer using this because it's less work/code to implement so I have to ask.

Also, thanks for react-admin. I love it :)